# Rotating coordinates after Translate

Tags: processing

Is there a way to actually rotate the coordinate system?

I want to be able to constantly say x=x+1 but have the circle move around in different angles using translate, similar to Turtle Graphics, and don't want to use the Y axis at all.

I've tried the rotate function but that only rotates the object not the direction its moving in unless im doing something wrong? and I'm not to familiar with vectors just yet to work with them comfortably.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the `rotate()` function as rotating the camera. It does rotate the coordinate system, just not in the way you're talking about.

In fact, I would argue that Turtle Graphics doesn't rotate the coordinate system at all, it rotates the Turtle. You could do this by keeping track of some variables and doing the rotations and drawings yourself:

```
float turtleX;
float turtleY;
float turtleHeading = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  turtleX = width/3;
  turtleY = height/4;
}

void draw() {

  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);
  rotateTurtle(45);
  forward(100);

  noLoop();
}

void forward(float amount) {
  float newX = turtleX + cos(radians(turtleHeading)) * amount;
  float newY = turtleY + sin(radians(turtleHeading)) * amount;

  line(turtleX, turtleY, newX, newY);
  ellipse(newX, newY, 10, 10);
  turtleX = newX;
  turtleY = newY;
}

void rotateTurtle(float degrees) {
  turtleHeading += degrees;
}
```

Or you could encapsulate that using a class:

```
Turtle turtle;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  turtle = new Turtle(width/3, height/4);
}

void draw() {

  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.rotate(45);
  turtle.forward(100);


  noLoop();
}

class Turtle {

  float x;
  float y;
  float heading = 0;

  public Turtle(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void forward(float amount) {
    float newX = x + cos(radians(heading)) * amount;
    float newY = y + sin(radians(heading)) * amount;

    line(x, y, newX, newY);
    ellipse(newX, newY, 10, 10);
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }

  void rotate(float degrees) {
    heading += degrees;
  }
}
```

[image: turtle]

This is just a basic example, but hopefully it shows what I'm talking about. You could add to this class to make it fancier, and you could even import this as a library if you were, for example, using this to teach students and wanted to hide the details of the class from them.

But I would take a step back and ask you why you want to use this type of thing. If you're just playing around then that's cool, but you also might want to consider trying to "think in Processing" a little more. Processing uses an absolute coordinate system instead of a relative Turtle (or pen), and all of its functions are designed with that in mind. Trying to force a different style of thinking onto that sorta defeats the purpose, imho.

But like I said, if you're just doing this to play around, then that's cool!

Comment: Thank you a lot, I asked because Ive only been using processing for a few weeks and have come from years of turtle experience, i didn't mean turtle rotated the coordinates I was just after a basic idea to make it work in a similar way so i could transfer some of the projects Ive made into processing a lot easier, i think its going to take quite a while to get into the processing head space but this gives me an idea of how to get around it.

Comment: @PyNuts Understood. I've edited my answer to include a simpler example that doesn't require a class.